# Generate WSDL file (inline schema) in Weblogic 12

Tags: web-services, wsdl, weblogic, jax-ws, wsgen

I use Weblogic 12c and I created an EJB web service using annotations: `@Stateless` and `@WebService`.
The WSDL file of this web service will be generated by Weblogic at run time, by default Weblogic decides not to use inline schemas. What should I do to have a single wsdl file for my web service?
I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293852/single-wsdl-with-no-schema-imports-in-weblogic-with-jax-ws) post, but I do not know how to use `-inlineSchemas` parameter in Weblogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot but there is nothing to solve this problem systematically for example by setting a parameter in Weblogic management panel.
I finally decided to solve it manually, I wrote a script to generate WSDL file with `-inlineSchemas` parameter. Beacause I used `@EJB` in my class I had to use `javaee-api.jar` file. I downloaded the jar file and put it near `.bat` file (I using Windows 10). In the .bat file there should be something like below:

```
wsgen -wsdl -inlineSchemas -cp .;javaee-api-6.0.jar qualified.name.of.your.class -r DESTINATION-OF-WSDL-FILE
```

Then in eclipse, I created a new builder for my project:

> Right click on the project in Project Explorer -> Properties ->
>   Builders -> New... -> Program

and in the next window I set The Location and Working Directory of my program. Then every time that I build the project (Using Ctrl+B to build all projects) new WSDL file will be generated from `qualified.name.of.your.class`.